# Get a file from remote login with known address

Tags: ssh, localhost

I haved ssh-ed to a remote cluster and figured out an address: `file://localhost/archive/path/to/the/file/filename.something`. How can it I download over the network? Also please explain what such as address means opposed to something like: `/home/somedir/path/to/the/file/filename.something`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## scp

You can use `scp`(OpenSSH secure file copy) to download or upload files between your host and remote. just assume your remote ip is `43.224.34.73`

**copy from host to remote:**

upload directory `/root/lk` to remote's directory `/home/lk/cpfile`

```
scp -r /root/lk root@43.224.34.73:/home/lk/cpfile
```

**copy from remote to host:**

download remote's `/home/lk/`to your host's `/root`:

```
scp -r root@43.224.34.73:/home/lk /root
```

## other tools

If you are using tools like `xshell`, there are some integrated tools with interactive GUI, like `rz`(upload) and `sz`(download), see https://blog.actorsfit.com/a?ID=00850-983aedfb-0a2e-425d-8fce-f54197b12caf